# ul li display inline-block not displaying horizontally

Tags: html-lists, css

I had everything working fine, then I was cleaning up css and moved some stuff around. Ilost my horizontal menu bar, it all went vertical:$

Ive been tweeking and searched the site for hours and still no luck. Might be a simple error in my code. I am pretty sure its something in css.

Would prefer not to have to use float....

Thanks for your assistance....

I might have a bit more code than need. this is where is got it
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PN1iMaVfzfQ

**Website:**
http://www.enhancedliving.ca/

**CSS:**

```
#menu_Box{   /*MENU BOX CONTAINER*/
 width: 890px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
#menu_Box ul{ /*MENU BOX STYLE*/
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#263A75;  
font-size:24px; 
font-weight:normal;
padding:0 0 0 10px;
margin:0;
    position:relative;
}
.extraStyle{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#263A75;  
font-size:24px;
font-weight:normal;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#menu_Box ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
#menu_Box ul li:hover{
    color:#456692;
}
#menu_Box ul li a,visited{
text-align:left;
color:#263A75;  
display:block;
padding: 0 0 0 0; /*Padding between titles*/ 
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu_Box ul li a:hover{
color:#456692;
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu_Box ul li:hover ul{
display:block; 
}

/*  ###############  DROP DOWN MENU BOX  ################  */   

#menu_Box ul ul{ /*Drop Down Box*/
    border: 3px solid rgba(0, 57, 96, .85) ;
display:none;
position:absolute;
background-color: rgba(139, 183, 212, .9);
    padding: 3px; /*Padding between list items*/    
}
#menu_Box ul ul li{ /*Drop Down Style*/
    display: block;
}
#menu_Box ul ul li a,visited{
color:#263A75;  
}
#menu_Box ul ul li a:hover{
    color:#456692;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>

   <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php">Services</a>

         <ul>
           <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2pk">Psych-K</a> </li>
           <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2fat">Food & Environmental Allergy and Sensitivity Testing</a> </li>
           <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2sne">Supplement and Nutrition Evaluation</a> </li>
           <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2fvt">Food Value Testing</a> </li>
        </ul> 
   </li> <p class="extraStyle">::</p> 


   <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/sessions.php">Sessions</a> </li> <p class="extraStyle">::</p>

   <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/bio.php">Biography</a> </li> <p class="extraStyle">::</p>

   <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/forums.php">Health Topics</a> </li><p class="extraStyle">::</p>

   <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/products.php">Favorite Products</a> </li><p class="extraStyle">::</p>

   <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/contact.php">Contact</a> </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for that

Thats another way of doing it. I may try it but, I do prefer list as well.

Then my next question is ... To get the list to work horizontally, where do i add the float and clear float.

Comment: Wow thanks rings. Yup that <p> tag in html was totally messing it up.

Kudos to you friend :)

Comment: Another fix with to add  Display:Inline  to .extraStyle{}  :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
<p class="extraStyle">::</p>
```

Into

```
<span class="extraStyle">::</span>
```